# Refresh plot after changing the underlying dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several large R scripts in which I construct complex plots. At the end, I want to output the plots as PDF and TikZ file. It looks something like this:

```
mydata <- ...
p <- ggplot(mydata, ...)
p <- p + ...  # many
p <- p + ...  # modifications
p <- p + ...  # to the plot
ggsave("plot.pdf")
ggsave("plot.tex", device=tikz)
```

Now, I want to change the name of factor levels between both calls to `ggsave`, since I want to include some fancy LaTeX stuff in the level names for the TikZ version:

```
ggsave("plot.pdf")
mydata$myfactor <- revalue(mydata$myfactor, c(small="S", medium="M"))
ggsave("plot.tex", device=tikz)
```

The problem here is that the change in `mydata` is not "propagated" to the plot. The TikZ version still uses the old level names. Is there any command to "refresh" the plot from `mydata`?

I'm aware of some workarounds, e.g., after renaming the factor levels, I could duplicate the whole plot construction. That works, but is inelegant. I think some kind of refresh-plot-from-data command would be most elegant, so that I don't have to repeat the plot specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given a reproducible example, but I think the `%+%` operator (which is primarily intended for replacing the internally stored  data set with a new, different one) should work to replace the internally stored data set with an updated version.

```
ggsave("plot.pdf",plot=p)
mydata$myfactor <- revalue(mydata$myfactor, c(small="S", medium="M"))
p <- p %+% mydata
ggsave("plot.tex", plot=p, device=tikz)
```

(I'm using an explicit `plot=` specification here for clarity.)

If that doesn't work, I would wrap your plot-construction code in a function, so that you would just `p <- build_plot(mydata)` every time you needed to.

Comment: `%+%` is exactly the functionality I was looking for.